# How to disable Winamp browsers?

Tags: windows-7, winamp

I just installed the Winamp 5.63.

How can I turn off / disable the Browser pan and the browser in the Media Library, or the whole Media Library pan? I do not want the player to go to the Internet without my intention.

In the Preferences -> General Preferences -> Internet Connection Settings I set "Not connected to the Internet".

Despite that, every time I play a new song the player opens the bowser tab and loads some page into it, and when I am not connected to the Internet it displays a error page with every new song. Kind of annoying.

Comment: Please edit this and split it into two individual questions.  When you do, please include what you've tried already, and where you're getting stuck accomplishing your goals.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to prevent winamp from connecting to the internet you can simply disable it in windows firewall. Be aware this will prevent it from adding album covers, album and artists details, etc to the library and prevent it from letting you know when the updates are available.

If you wish to turn off the library pan, you will notice everything from the play and pause buttons to the adjustments to the audio levels is in a separate window you can pull away from the whole thing, you can simply click the X in the top right of any of the pans and they wont appear when it starts up unless you enable them again.

As for milkdrop, no sorry you can't adjust the presets.

Comment: Hi, user88311! Thanks for your help. If I block Winamp with the firewall, the effect will be the same as when I have no connection: it will be showing me the error page with every song. I want to be able to use visualizations. If I collapse the whole lower window, then how do I launch visualizations, and would it also turn off the browsers?